# How do I find if $\frac{e^x}{x^3} = 2x + 1$ has an algebraic solution?

Tags: exponentiation, roots, closed-form

Is there some way of solving $$\frac{e^x}{x^3} = 2x + 1 $$
non-numerically?
How would I go about proving if there exists a closed form solution? Similarly how would I go about proving if there exists an analytic solution?

Comment: Sounds like [Lambert W](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)?

Comment: @AméricoTavares I think you mean $e^x - 2 x^{\color{red}{4}} - x^3 = 0.$

Comment: @J.D. Thanks. Yes, it was a mistake. If you type e^x-2x^4-x^3=0 in WolframAlpha it gives you three roots x≈-0.84922, x≈0.963883 and x≈9.92089, none with exact form.

Comment: There might be a simple (infinite) continued fraction expansion. Anyone know how to find that?

Comment: No, Lambert W won't help for this one. It would if the $+1$ wasn't there.

Comment: The ISC does not recognize 9.9208858961766

Comment: The simple continued fraction of the root near $1$ begins $[0; 1, 26, 1, 2, 4, 1, 29, 5, 10, 42, 3, 1, 3, 96, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4,\ldots]$, i.e. $$0+\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{26+\dfrac{1}{1+\ldots}}}$$
I doubt that there is a closed form for the elements.

Comment: @GEdgar what is ISC? Is it a software?

Comment: @J.D.: [Inverse Symbolic Calculator](http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GEdgar answers the question of proving that there's no *algebraic* closed form solution, i.e. a solution that is an [algebraic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number) (a root of some finite degree polynomial with rational coefficients). However, as he mentions, if there were such a solution $a$, then $a^3(2a+1)$ would also be algebraic, and couldn't equal $e^a$ which would be transcendental by Lindemann's theorem.

The best that you can do is to solve it numerically, e.g. with Newton's method. You could use the [Lagrange inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem) formula (as Robert Israel does), or perhaps some variation of Lambert's W function or an infinite continued fraction expansion for each of the three real solutions.

The best general technique to find real solutions is to first locate the solutions, then use an appropriate iterative method to get the required accuracy. In this case, an excellent method that you could even do by hand if you had to would be to graph $e^x$ (in blue below) versus the polynomial $x^3(2x+1)$ (in red). Because of the contrast in scale near the origin, where there are two roots, and away from it in the first quadrant, where the third root lies, it is not possible to depict these on a linear scale (without ellipsis). So I show the important views below. The first graph, of the polynomial RHS near the origin, you should be able to sketch purely from looking at the factored form. Knowing the shape of an exponential $e^x$, and knowing that it always eventually outgrows any polynomial, you can then deduce that there must be three roots.

[image: x^3(2x+1) near its roots]
[image: small roots near -.85 and .9]
[image: large root near 9.92]
[image: portion in first quadrant where polynomial is greater]

As @RobertIsrael pointed out, there are actually infinitely many complex numbers satisfying the equation. If we rewrite it with the customary variables $z=x+iy=re^{i\theta}$ (i.e., with $z$ in stead of $x$), the equation becomes
$$
e^x(\cos y+i\sin y) = e^z = w = 2z^3 \left( z+\frac12 \right) = 2z^4+z^3.
$$
Now we can treat the right and left sides as two functions
$w=f(z)=e^z$ and $w=g(z)=2z^4+z^3$ in the complex plane.
The exponential function $f(z)$ takes each vertical line to a circle (a covering map).
The imaginary axis gets mapped to the unit circle, with $0$ sent to $1$ and preserving length. Lines with fixed $x$ are first scaled by $r=e^x$ and then wrapped around the circle of radius $r$ centered at the origin. Each vertical line is mapped surjectively (and periodically) onto the corresponding circle. Each horizontal strip $y\in\left(2\pi t-\pi,2\pi t+\pi\right]$ (for each $t\in\mathbb{R}$) is consequently mapped smoothly and *injectively* onto $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ by $z\rightarrow e^z$. So much for the left hand side. The right hand side is a degree $4$ polynomial map. As a function of its real and imaginary components, it is
$$
g(z) =
2y^4 - i(8x+1)y^3 - 3x(4x+1)y^2 + ix^2(8x+3)y + x^3(2x+1) =
$$
$$
\left(
2y^4
 - 3x(4x+1)y^2
 + x^3(2x+1)
\right)
+
\left(
 - (8x+1)y^3
 + x^2(8x+3)y
\right)\,i
$$
and as a function of its polar variables, it is
$$
g(z) =
2z^4+z^3
= r^3 e^{3i\theta} \left( 2 \, r e^{i\theta} + 1 \right)
= 2 \, r^4 e^{4i\theta} + r^3 e^{3i\theta}
$$
from which we can see that circles centered at the origin
get mapped to closed curves with some fixed total curvature.
Here are plots of the image of $r=1$, $r=2$, and $r=\frac12$
(identifiable by their scale), which each have rotation index $4$
and total curvature $8\pi$. In contrast, the [winding number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number)
is not constant over the curve's interior because the curve
intersects itself multiple times and hence is also not simple.

[image: r=1]

[image: r=2]
[image: r=1/2]

Of course, the exponential map $f(z)$ also maps circles to closed curves,
and in particular, it maps central circles $z=re^{i\theta}$ with fixed $r$
to curves with reciprocal positive real intercepts
and unit [winding number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number) about $w=1$.
To investigate these images, let us note
that for $r > 0$ fixed and constant,
$$
\left.
\eqalign{
 & x+iy=z=re^{i\theta} \\\\
 & \frac{dz}{d\theta}=iz=-y+ix
}
\right\}
\qquad
\implies
\qquad
\eqalign{
 \frac{dx}{d\theta}&=-&y=-&r\sin\theta \\\\
 \frac{dy}{d\theta}&= &x= &r\cos\theta
}
$$
so that for $w=f(z)$,
$$
\left.
\eqalign{
 & u+iv = w=e^z = \frac{dw}{dz} \\\\
 & \eqalign{
   \frac{dw}{d\theta}
 &= \frac{dw}{dz}\,\frac{dz}{d\theta}
  = w \cdot iz
  = ire^{x+i(y+\theta)} \\\\&
  = izw = i(x+iy)(u+iv) \\\\&
  = -(xv+yu)+(xu-yv)i
 }
}
\right\}
\qquad
\implies
\qquad
\eqalign{
 \frac{du}{d\theta}&=-&re^x\sin(\theta+y) \\\\
 \frac{dv}{d\theta}&= &re^x\cos(\theta+y) \\\\
 \frac{dv}{du}     &=-&\cot(\theta+r\sin\theta)
}
$$
Identifiying $f$ and $g$ with real functions
$F,G:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$,
$$
\eqalign{
F(r,\theta)
&=f(z)
 =e^{r\cos\theta}
  \left(
   \cos\left(r\sin\theta\right),~
   \sin\left(r\sin\theta\right)
  \right)
\\\\
G(r,\theta)
&=g(z)
 =r^3
 \left(
   2r\cos{4\theta}
    +\cos{3\theta},~
   2r\sin{4\theta}
    +\sin{3\theta}
 \right)
}
$$
our complex equation becomes a system of two simultaneous real equations:
$$
\eqalign{
 e^{r\cos\theta}
   \cos\left(r\sin\theta\right)
 &=
 r^3
 \left(
   2r\cos{4\theta}
    +\cos{3\theta}
 \right)
 =
 r^3
 \left(
   2r\,T_4\left(\cos\theta)\right)
      +T_3\left(\cos\theta)\right)
 \right)
\\\\
 e^{r\cos\theta}
   \sin\left(r\sin\theta\right)
 &=
 r^3
 \left(
   2r\sin{4\theta}
    +\sin{3\theta}
 \right)
 =
 r^3
 \left(
   2r\,U_4\left(\cos\theta)\right)
      +U_3\left(\cos\theta)\right)
 \right)
 \sin\theta
}
$$
where $T_i$ and $U_i$ are [Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Examples) of the first and second kind, respectively.

Comment: Why would a closed form solution have to be algebraic?  Perhaps there is a solution that is a rational multiple of $\pi$ (I doubt it, but I see no way of disproving it).

Comment: By the way, there are infinitely many solutions, of which three are real.

Comment: @Robert, those are both great points, thanks. I will try to update my post and do the question justice.

Answer (score 5):

If you write your equation as, say, $f(x)=t$ where $f(x) = e^x - 2 x^4 - x^3$, you can use the Lagrange inversion formula to get power series solutions.  A convenient starting point is $f(1)=e-3$.  Taking $a=1$ and $b=f(a) = e-3$, the Lagrange inversion formula says that for $t$ near $b$, one solution of $f(x)=t$ is 
$$ g(t) = a + \frac{t-b}{f'(a)} + \sum_{n=2}^\infty \lim_{w \to a} \frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}}
\left(\frac{w-a}{f(w)-b}\right)^n \frac{(t-b)^n}{n!}$$ 
which in this case is
$$ g(t) = 1 + \frac{t-b}{e-11} + \frac{-e+30}{(e-11)^3} \frac{(t-b)^2}{2} + \frac{2 e^2 - 115 e +2106}{(e-11)^5} \frac{(t-b)^3}{6} + \frac{-6e^3+470 e^2 - 16237 e + 232608}{(e-11)^7} \frac{(t-b)^4}{24} + \ldots$$

Answer (score 3):

Lindemann's Theorem:  If $a$ is nonzero and algebraic, then $e^a$ is transcendental.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem
From this we see your equation has no algebraic solutions.

Note: your title does use the word "algebraic" ... even though your body says "analytic".

Comment: I think I mean to say analytic here :)

Comment: But there is no such thing as an "analytic number".  There are analytic functions...

Comment: I think he said "analytic solution" when he means "closed form solution"...

Comment: Yes, I suspect so.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, I give an answer for solutions in the reals.

$$\frac{e^x}{x^3}=2x+1$$
$$e^x=2x^4+x^3$$

Your equation is an equation of [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function). It's an algebraic equation in dependence of $e^x$ and $x$. Because the terms $e^x,x$ are algebraically independent and the equation is irreducible, we don't know how to rearrange the equation for $x$ by only elementary operations (means elementary functions).
A theorem of Lin (1983) proves, if Schanuel's conjecture is true, that irreducible algebraic equations involving both $e^x$ and $x$ don't have solutions in the [elementary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_number).

$$1=(2x+1)x^3e^{-x}$$
$$(2x+1)x^3e^{-x}=1$$
$x\to -t$:
$$(2t-1)t^3e^t=1$$
$$\left(t-\frac{1}{2}\right)t^3e^t=\frac{1}{2}$$

We see, your equation cannot be solved in terms of Lambert W but in terms of Generalized Lambert W.

$$t=W\left(^{\frac{1}{2},0,0,0}_{\ \ \ \ \ \ -};\frac{1}{2}\right)$$
$$x=-W\left(^{\frac{1}{2},0,0,0}_{\ \ \ \ \ \ -};\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

The inverse relation of your kind of equations is what Mezö et al. call $r$-Lambert function. They write:
"Depending on the parameter $r$, the $r$-Lambert function has one, two or three real branches and so the above equations can have one, two or three solutions"

So we have a closed form for $x$, and the representations of Generalized Lambert W give some hints for calculating $x$.

[Mező 2017] Mező, I.: On the structure of the solution set of a generalized Euler-Lambert equation. J. Math. Anal. Appl. 455 (2017) (1) 538-553

[Mező/Baricz 2017] Mező, I.; Baricz, Á.: On the generalization of the Lambert W function. Transact. Amer. Math. Soc. 369 (2017) (11) 7917–7934 [(On the generalization of the Lambert W function with applications in theoretical physics. 2015)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999)

[[Castle 2018] Castle, P.: Taylor series for generalized Lambert W functions. 2018](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.09904)